# Extract specific data from text

Tags: r

I have a single column with many rows with following geographical information:

Ø228818, N6575807 Sone 33 (±500m) UTM(WGS 84)

These are all merged in a single column, only separated with "," and " " .
I need to extract the "Sone XX" into an own column, but i haven`t found any suitable commands for this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried that did not work? Please add this information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
NewColumn = sub(".*\\b(Sone\\s+\\d+).*", "\\1", String)
NewColumn
[1] "Sone 33"
```

#### Some detail on the RegEx

The part in the middle `Sone\\s+\\d+` is what you want.
`Sone` is the literal string. `\\s+` matches one or more blanks. `\\d+` matches one or more digits, 0-9.  That group is enclosed in parentheses so that the result is stored for later use. The pattern is preceded and followed by `\\.*` to match everything else.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! However, if the data differs slightly in format, is there a logical way to pick up "sone XX" besides its location in the text?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The above regular expression does not depend on the location within the string. It only requires that the string say Sone <some number> somewhere. If there might be something between Sone and the number, this would need to be altered.

Comment: How to alter it if there is a "(" inbetween?
e.g. 

UTM(WGS 84)    # and keep "WGS 84"

Not too familiar with these regular expressions

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking.  Do you mean that UTM is followed by an expression in parentheses that you want to capture? Does this have anything to do with Sone?   You must make it clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explanation!! :)

Well, i mean that i also have to do a similar extraction of the "UTM(>>extract<<)"

Comment: The similar expression would be `sub(".*\\bUTM\\((.*?)\\).*", "\\1", String)`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help :)